# Animations in FBX exported from Maya are anchored in the wrong place

Tags: animation, unity, maya, fbx

We are trying to export a model and animation from Maya into Unity3d.

In Maya, the model is anchored (pivot point) at the feet (and the body moves up and down). However after we have performed the FBX export, and imported the file into Unity the model is now appears to be anchored by the waist/head and the feet move.

These example videos probably help explain the problem more clearly:

- [Example video - Maya - Correct](http://youtu.be/wxw5DsKfE3c)
- [Example video - Unity - Wrong](http://youtu.be/Ts0xb2vZRIE)

We have also noticed that if we take the FBX file and import it back into Maya we have exactly the same problem.

It seems to be that the constraints no longer work after the FBX is reimported back to Maya, which just kills the connection between the joints and the control objects.

When we exported the FBX we have tried checking the 'bake animations' check box.

The fact that the same problem exist when importing the FBX back into both Maya and Unity suggests that the source of the problem is most likely with the Maya FBX export.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was to bake the animations to the rig, and then delete the control objects including the IKs.